# innerHtml not working in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am trying to display a json string which contains line breaks and line returns; `\r` and `\n`

This is the json:

```
 {
   "Content": "OFCH\r\nPVC Double Glazed Windows\r\nMains Services"
 }
```

This is the HTML:

```
<p class="PropertyBrochure__DescriptionContent" [innerHTML]="description.Content"></p>
```

This is the output:

```
OFCH PVC Double Glazed Windows Mains Services
```

As you can see the `\r\n` in the json string are stripped and ignored.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The carriage returns are neither stripped nor ignored. The HTML will be resolved by Angular as:

```html
<p class="PropertyBrochure__DescriptionContent">OFCH
PVC Double Glazed Windows
Mains Services</p>
```

The problem is that the browser's HTML renderer collapses the white-space and expects you to use `<br>` elements to force new lines.

Alternatively, you can control the browser's handling of white-space using CSS (see documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)):

```css
.PropertyBrochure__DescriptionContent { white-space: pre; }
```

```html
<p class="PropertyBrochure__DescriptionContent">OFCH
PVC Double Glazed Windows
Mains Services</p>
```

Comment: Probably `pre-line` is prefereably over `pre`, as with `pre`, longer text will not wrap automatically.

Comment: @BlueM Good point, but difficult to tell what is required in a given situation. I'll add a link to the MDN documentation.